# To Clean or not to Clean

Tags: continuous-integration, build-process

I work on a medium sized project that uses continuous integration to perform regular builds. Our project has quite a long build time at the moment (45-55 mins) and we have been looking at what optimizations can be made to reduce this time.

One of the optimizations that has been suggested is to eliminate the clean step that we have at the start of every build ie delete the entire build directory and get **all** source files from source control. Instead, just retrieve the files that have been changed and start a new build. Rough estimates put this at saving us 10-20 mins per build but the suggestion made me a little uncomfortable.

So I turn to the Stack Overflow community to see what the best practise is... does your continuous integration always do a clean build? Are there particular reasons for and/or against this?

I'll post my thoughts below in an attempt not to bias anyone but am really interested to hear some other opinions.

Answer (score 1):

For continuous integration, it's important to have a rapid turnaround. I have made that trade-off before, and I would say it's worth it. Occasionally, it will allow things to slip through, but the gains in getting feedback sooner are worth it.

In addition to performing frequent incremental builds, have less frequent clean builds. This gives you most of the benefits of both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for continuous integration is to identify all problems early, not some of the problems quickly and the others - well, when ever.

Not cleaning provides an opportunity for a problem to go undetected for a significant amount of time. Most partial build systems still rely on file time stamps for integrity, need I say more.

Cleaning is often the only way to be certain the build is good. An alternate may be to clean periodically (say nightly), so the worst case is a day before a problem is detected (is that early enough?).

Whats you budget improved build servers. Can you make your build go faster - optimization, more/faster hardware, parallel build steps, faster compiler etc. Can you go to a faster build tool such as scons or similar, that will make use of the all 8 CPUs in your build server (particularly if you use make)?

I would Clean.

Comment: + 1 agree with your points. We are looking at the hardware as well and there is definitely room for improvement there

Answer (score 0):

Continuous Integration is all about repeatability.  If you can produce a reliable build each time without cleaning do it.  The problem with not removing the build directory is that file that are removed from SCM might not get removed from the build directory, and as a result could mess up deployments and testing.

Personally I would recommend cleaning your build directory, but not deleting your source.  This assumes your SCM can sync your source correctly.

---

It takes ~15 minutes to clean?  Thats a pretty long time, I would be interested in knowing what is taking so long.

Comment: I think we are over 10k files now (a large proportion of these are re-use components or source for Off The Shelf software). Deleting and then syncing all these files is painfull

Comment: How much time do you save if you just delete the build dir, and dont delete the source?